# SFML collision with specific tiles

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

I am making a platformer game with SFML and C++. I Loaded a tile set using the example given by sfml (https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-vertex-array.php) and tried adding collision detection between the player and certain tiles. The problem is, collision is detected with every tile and I don't know how to detect collision with only a certain tile index. The player is just a simple rectangle.

## world.cpp

```
bool World::loadTiles(const std::string& tile_set, sf::Vector2u tile_size, const int* tiles, unsigned int desired_width, unsigned int desired_height)
{
    if (!m_tileset.loadFromFile(tile_set))
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR:: Cannot load tileset from file" << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    m_vertices.setPrimitiveType(sf::Quads);
    m_vertices.resize(desired_width * desired_height * 4);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < desired_width; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < desired_height; ++j)
        {
            int tile_number = tiles[i + j * desired_width];

            // Find tile position in tileset
            int tu = tile_number % (m_tileset.getSize().x / tile_size.x);
            int tv = tile_number / (m_tileset.getSize().x / tile_size.x);

            // Get pointer to current tile quad
            sf::Vertex* quad = &m_vertices[(i + j * desired_width) * 4];

            // Define four corners of tile
            quad[0].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tile_size.x, j * tile_size.y);
            quad[1].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tile_size.x, j * tile_size.y);
            quad[2].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tile_size.x, (j + 1) * tile_size.y);
            quad[3].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tile_size.x, (j + 1) * tile_size.y);

            // Define tiles four texture coordinates
            quad[0].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tu * tile_size.x, tv * tile_size.y);
            quad[1].texCoords = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tile_size.x, tv * tile_size.y);
            quad[2].texCoords = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tile_size.x, (tv + 1) * tile_size.y);
            quad[3].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tu * tile_size.x, (tv + 1) * tile_size.y);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void World::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    states.transform *= getTransform();

    states.texture = &m_tileset;

    target.draw(m_vertices, states);
}

 void World::collision(Players& players)
{
    auto player = players.player;

    if (m_vertices.getBounds().intersects(player.getGlobalBounds()))
    {
        std::cout << "collision" << "\n";
    }
}
```

## world.hpp

```
class World : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
public:
    bool loadTiles(const std::string& tile_set, sf::Vector2u tile_size, const int* tiles, unsigned int desired_width, unsigned int desired_height);
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
    void collision(Players& players);
private:
    sf::VertexArray m_vertices;
    sf::Texture m_tileset;

};
```

## game.cpp

```
int x = -1;

const int level[] =
{
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
};
    

int tile_width = 32;
int tile_height = 32;
int desired_width = 32;
int desired_height = 17;
World world_map;
if (!world_map.loadTiles("content/ground-tileset.png", sf::Vector2u(tile_width, tile_height), level, desired_width, desired_height))
{
    std::cout << "ERROR:: Cannot load tile map from file" << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is `m_vertices` an `sf::VertexArray` containing the vertrices for _one_ tile? Is `players.player` also an `sf::VertexArray` containing the vertrices for _one_ player? Please show a [mre] so we can see the definitions.

Comment: @TedLyngmo m_vertices holds all the tiles. But all of the tiles have to be in the same one or the dirt tiles go to the top of the screen.

Comment: Then that's the problem.  `m_vertices.getBounds()` returns the bounds of _all_ vertrices and the bounding rect will most probably cover all or most of the whole screen. Create separate containers: `sf::VertexArray dirt_tiles;` etc. and `draw` them in the order you want. Dirt first (I presume). For tiles you want to check for collisions, you need one `sf::VertexArray` per tile, so `std::vector<sf::VertexArray>`.

Comment: ... then loop over all the tiles and check one by one for a collision with the player.

Comment: @TedLyngmo But then wouldn't the dirt just go to the top of screen. Because I couldn't find a way to change the position of the tilemap.

Comment: Look at the `TileMap` in the tutorial. I think that shows how you transform what needs to be drawn.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The tutorial says that it works for transformable types. I would have to make the tiles into sprites and I don't know how to do that. That would also solve the collision problem.

Comment: The `TileMap` in the tutorial uses a plain `sf::VertexArray` with `sf::Quads` to paint all the tiles. The class is transformable because it inherits from `sf::Transformable`. Anyway, that's for painting the dirt where you don't need collision detection (I presume). If you need collision detection, you need one `sf::VertexArray` per object you want to check for a collision with.

Comment: You can have a `std::vector<sf::Rect<int/float>>`, where you would only store the tiles that needs collision.

Comment: @TedLyngmo so how would i change the position of the tiles I want to detect collision with. they are at the bottom of the screen now but that's because the rest of the screen is filled with invisible (x) tiles. But when I put the dirt into its own vertex array, the dirt just goes to the top again. (sorry for so many questions)

Comment: That was quick :-) You're welcome!

Comment: @TedLyngmo That actually just changes the position of the texture not the actual tile.

Comment: @AidenRand I think a small [mre] would be great. I don't know _that_ much about SFML so if you give me something small to work with, I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @TedLyngmo If I add anymore it's gonna be all my code. you can get the code from here https://github.com/Cortrax/bop-vs-pob

Comment: No, not more, less. The most minimal code possible. It doesn't have to be more than a tile or two that ends up in the wrong place.